# Passing anonymous classes to private member functions

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use a class defined in an anonymous namespace as a parameter in a private member function?  I haven’t found a way to forward declare AnonymousHelperClass in the header.

```
// C.h
class C
{
  // ...
private:
  void Boing(AnonymousHelperClass &helper);
};
```

.

```
// C.cpp
namespace
{
  class AnonymousHelperClass
  {
    // . . . 
  };
}

C::Boing(AnonymousHelperClass &helper)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because there is no way to name the type in the header file.

However, you could turn the private member function into a template:

```
// C.h
class C
{
public:

    void Foo();

private:
    template <typename TAnonymousHelper>
    void Boing(TAnonymousHelper&);
};
```

Then define it in the source file and use it with the `AnonymousHelperClass`:

```
// C.cpp
#include "C.h"

namespace
{
    class AnonymousHelperClass { };
}

template <typename TAnonymousHelper>
void C::Boing(TAnonymousHelper& x) { }

void C::Foo()
{
    AnonymousHelperClass x;
    Boing(x);
}
```

Though really, it's probably easier just to rework your logic such that the private member function can be a namespace-scope function in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

No, because *unnamed namespaces* (that's what they're actually called) are defined like this in the C++ standard:

> **7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces [namespace.unnamed]**
>
> *1.* An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
>     namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
>     using namespace unique;
>     namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where all occurrences of unique in a translation unit are replaced by
>   the same identifier and this identifier differs from all other
>   identifiers in the entire program.

So with your class it's equivalent to:

```
namespace SomeUniqueNameGeneratedByTheCompiler {}
using namespace SomeUniqueNameGeneratedByTheCompiler;
namespace SomeUniqueNameGeneratedByTheCompiler
{    
    class AnonymousHelperClass    
    {    
        // . . .     
    };    
}
```

So the full qualification of the `AnonymousHelperClass` class is `::SomeUniqueNameGeneratedByTheCompiler::AnonymousHelperClass`, not `::AnonymousHelperClass`. So even if you did this:

```
class AnonymousHelperClass; // Forward declaration

class C     
{     
  // ...     
private:     
  void Boing(AnonymousHelperClass &helper);     
};
```

That forward declaration refers to a different `AnonymousHelperClass`. You could put the forward declaration in the `SomeUniqueNameGeneratedByTheCompiler` namespace, but since only the compiler knows this name, it can't be done.

Comment: And if you did that, the compiler would choose a different unique name anyway.